# How to detect if two sprites are being touched at the same time?

Tags: java, libgdx, touch

I tried this:

```
if(spr.getBoundingRectangles.contain(x,y)){
    //do this
}
```

but how to detect if the other sprite is touched by the second pointer?

EDIT:

```
for(int i = 0; i < Constants.MAX_POINTERS; i++){
           if(Gdx.input.isTouched(i)){
               xy.set(Gdx.input.getX(i), Gdx.input.getY(i), 0);
               xy1.set(Gdx.input.getX(i), Gdx.input.getY(i), 0);
               WorldRenderer.camera.unproject(xy);
               WorldRenderer.camera.unproject(xy1);

               if(Spr.getBoundingRectangle().contains(xy.x, xy.y) &&
                       Spr1.getBoundingRectangle().contains(xy.x, xy.y))
                   score += 1;
           }
       }
```

What happens is that `xy` and `xy1` are always the same, when I touch the screen with the second pointer they will just both switch to the new coordinates instead of having two different x,y for both xy and xy1.

Answer (score 1):

you can iterate over all pointers checking whether they are touching the screen and then check if positions overlapping sprites position

```
    final int MAX_POINTERS = 5;

    ...

    for(int i = 0; i < MAX_POINTERS; i++)
    {
        if( Gdx.input.isTouched(i) )
        {
            int x = Gdx.input.getX(i);
            int y = Gdx.input.getY(i);

            if( sprite.getBoundingRectangle().contains(x, y) ) //instead of checking one sprite iterate over sprites array
            {
                System.out.println("The sprite is touched!");
            }

            //if... - or just add more ifs
        }
    }
```

you need to define max count of pointers to iterate over it - as far as I know Libgdx supports up to 20 pointers

---

ABOUT EDIT:

Of course they are the same... :) You are placing **the same value to vetors**. My example above is far more generic that you need - if you know that you have **two pointers** you can just use:

```
if( Gdx.input.isTouched(0) && Gdx.input.isTouched(1) ) //because if two pointers are touching screen there is a chance that they are touching two sprites
{
    xy.set(Gdx.input.getX(0), Gdx.input.getY(0), 0);
    xy1.set(Gdx.input.getX(1), Gdx.input.getY(1), 0);

    //checking if pointer 1 is touching sprite 1 and pointer 2 is touching sprite 2 OR VICE VERSA
    if( (Spr.getBoundingRectangle().contains(xy.x, xy.y) && Spr1.getBoundingRectangle().contains(xy1.x, xy1.y))
        ||
        (Spr.getBoundingRectangle().contains(xy1.x, xy1.y) && Spr1.getBoundingRectangle().contains(xy.x, xy.y)) 
      )
    {
        score += 1;
    }
}
```

or just create the function that will return true if all sprites you will pass to it are touched (which actually will can handle more than two sprites)

```
boolean allTouched(Array<Sprite> sprites)
{
    int spritesCount = sprites.size;
    int spritesTouched = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < MAX_POINTERS; i++)
    {
        if( Gdx.input.isTouched(i) )
        {
            for(Sprite sprite : sprites)
            {
                if( sprite.getBoundingRectangle().contains(Gdx.input.getX(i), Gdx.input.getY(i)) )
                {
                    spritesTouched++;
                    sprites.removeValue(sprite, true); //to not doubling the same sprite
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return spritesCount == spritesTouched ;
}
```